# Screen flickers after Google Sign In dialog dismiss android studio

Tags: android, firebase, dialog, google-signin

I'm facing this issue and am not able to find a solution to it. I have Google Sign In implemented in my app using firebase. The problem I'm facing is that whenever the Sign In dialog dismisses a black strip runs across the screen from top to bottom. It moves very fast but still is noticeable. I want to remove this black strip that runs across the screen so the user smoothly returns to the screen.

I tried to add

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

in onPause() and onResume() methods but still found no success.

Could anybody please help me to find a way around this and/or how could I achieve it?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and it bothered me, it didn't look good.

I found a solution! You can define activity open and close animations in `styles.xml` and assign them to the activity which starts the google sign in by using `android:windowAnimationStyle`. Here is an example using fade animations:

`styles.xml`:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/ActivityAnimations</item>
</style>

<style name="ActivityAnimations" parent="@android:style/Animation.Activity">
    <item name="android:activityOpenEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityOpenExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseEnterAnimation">@anim/fade_in</item>
    <item name="android:activityCloseExitAnimation">@anim/fade_out</item>
</style>
```

The style `AppTheme` is assigned to the application or the activity that launches the google sign in flow in the `AndroidManifest.xml` using `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`.

FadeIn:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="500"
    />
```

FadeOut:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="500"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

To the Google Sign In Intent add a flag:

```
signInIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```

After calling `startActivityForResult(signInIntent, REQ_CODE)` add:

```
activity.overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by adding `<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>` in the `styles.xml`

```xml
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
  </style>
...
```