# Google plus dilaog black stripe issue after login

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have Google Sign In implemented in my app using firebase. The problem I'm facing is that whenever the Sign In dialog dismisses a black strip runs across the screen from top to bottom. It moves very fast but still is noticeable. I want to remove this black strip that runs across the screen so the user smoothly returns to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this. Seems like only happens to some specific sign in.

[Screen flickers after Google Sign In dialog dismiss android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56484002/screen-flickers-after-google-sign-in-dialog-dismiss-android-studio)